# Not enough space for ad on Android View

Tags: android, layout, space

I want to display ad in my app. 
In Landscape-Mode it works, but in normal mode it doesn't. 
Message in logcat is: `"Not enough space to show ad!"`

This is my main xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">


    <DigitalClock 
        android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/countdown"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/timeButtons"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <de.sms.android.babyschlafvibrator.free.CountdownPicker
                android:id="@+id/hour_picker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </de.sms.android.babyschlafvibrator.free.CountdownPicker>

            <de.sms.android.babyschlafvibrator.free.CountdownPicker
                android:id="@+id/minute_picker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </de.sms.android.babyschlafvibrator.free.CountdownPicker>

            <de.sms.android.babyschlafvibrator.free.CountdownPicker
                android:id="@+id/second_picker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </de.sms.android.babyschlafvibrator.free.CountdownPicker>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomButtons"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="@string/start"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stopButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="@string/stop"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exitButton"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="@string/exit"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/addLayout"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My code is:

```
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxx");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addLayout);
    layout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But the code is not the problem - in landscape mode it works...

Comment: Where exactly is the code of your AD?

Comment: There's obviously not enough space. Set different background colors on all your LinearLayouts so you can work out what view is taking up what space.

Comment: @gian1200: I just added my code

Comment: You should also rework your xml. Why so many LinearLayouts? If you don't define an orientation, all are going to be horizontals. Is that AdMob? why not use the xml implementation? it is easier and you can see it on the Eclipse Preview

Comment: yes, this is admob. In documentation, this solution was recommended. This is only a excert of my xml. I didn't want to post the whole xml

Comment: @streeter: Why not? Is it shameful?

Comment: hrhr ;) I wanted to hold it briefly. But now You can see my complete xml

Answer (score 1):

Try using an AdSize.SmartBanner, it automatically chooses the best size ad for the current screen.

Comment: I already  tried it, but got: "Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50, but only has 288x109"

Comment: What device are you using? That is an incredibly small. Have you tried changing the addview android:layout_width="wrap_content" to be "fill_parent"?

Comment: with fill_parent I get "Not enough space to show ad. Needs 480x32, but only has 448x69" - I use a Xperia Mini Pro (3", really small). But on a Xperia Sola with 3,7" it also does not work :(

Answer (score -1):

just remove

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

from Linear layout and your problem is solved